# Submenu with pure html and css disappears

Tags: html, css, submenu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu with pure html and css, but the submenus disappear when the cursor leaves the parent li, thus preventing me from clicking on the submenu. Here is a link to the test site, [link text](http://www-stud.uni-due.de/~sdroawem/shesa/shesasite/layout.html)

I would really appreciate some help.

Roland A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `content` div is above the menu and takes the mouseover out of your menu.. set the `ul` to have `position:relative` and `z-index:100` and it should work..

***update***

actually just add `z-index:100;` to the `#navigation` rule